Docker volume backup creates root:root owned files
I'm trying to backup a docker volume by tar-ing the contents and copying that out of the container using a bind mount (I think). The command is:
docker run --rm -v ./$BACKUPDIR:/backup -v docker_wordpress_log_wordpress:/var/www/html debian sh -c "/bin/tar -czf /backup/wordpress_$BKTIME.tar.gz /var/www/html"
The resulting tar in my $BACKUPDIR has root:root ownership even though the docker is running through my non-root user, and crontab is also running as the same user. I'm unable to change the permissions in the above by simply adding && chown <user>:<user> <file> because the user/group does not exist in the debian environment. I suppose the same script I can make a user w/ the same name as my system, but this is starting to get rather kludgy.
How do I create a tar of a volume that is owned by the user running the crontab/docker commands?
I could in principle run crontab as root to change permissions of these files for my user, but that's now making multiple steps that could fail before transfering the backups offsite, not to mention linking them in time.
Changing the permissions in the docker container isn't possible without making the user/group in the docker image which is temporary, and should be agnostic to the host system anyway.

The container runs as whichever USER is specified in its Dockerfile, or root if nothing else is.  Do you need a docker run -u $(id -u) option to run it as a different user?

This feels like a hack, and should not be the solution in my opinion because the UID:GID is not in principal uniform across systems, but it's working for now.
UIDGID=`id -u`:`id -g`

docker run --rm -v ./$BACKUPDIR:/backup -v docker_wordpress_log_wordpress:/var/www/html debian sh -c "/bin/tar -czf /backup/wordpress_$BKTIME.tar.gz /var/www/html && chown $UIDGID /backup/wordpress_$BKTIME.tar.gz"

